# Restrict su to a group of users

Tags: su

Is there someway to restrict `su` to a specific group of users?

Upon searching over the web, I came across IBM AIX's concept of `sugroup`. Whenever a user is created, attribute `sugroup` can be set; and only members of this group are allowed to su to that user.

`sugroup` can help me solve my problem by creating a group which contains only certain users allowed to su. Assigning `sugroup` means users outside this group are not permitted to be su-ed to by other users. But this concept of `sugroup` is not available in Ubuntu. How can it be achieved in Ubuntu?

I made following entry in `/etc/pam.d/su`:

`auth       required   pam_wheel.so group=sulogin`

I created following:

- a group called `sulogin` which is for users allowed to su
- users who don't belong to `sulogin` are `user1` and `user2`
- users who do belong to `sulogin` are `admin1` and `admin2`

Now when I am logged in as `user1` and try to su to `admin1` or `admin2`, I am not permitted to do so. This is as per my requirement. When I am logged in as `user1` and try to su to `user2`, I am not permitted to do this. This is not as per my requirement (although my requirements were not clearly mentioned in the original question).

I need to restrict all the users who are not in group `sulogin` from su-ing to any user who belongs to `sulogin` group. Basically, 2 levels of su privilege. So in the above mentioned scenario:

- `user1` should be able to `su` to `user2` and vice-versa
- `user1` or `user2` should not be able to `su` to `admin1` or `admin2`
- `admin1` should be able to `su` to `user1` or `user2`

Comment: At that level of complexity, I'd advice you to ditch su altogether and stick with sudo.

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent is possible on Ubuntu, it's just not enabled by default. Check out `/etc/pam.d/su`:

```
# Uncomment this to force users to be a member of group root
# before they can use `su'. You can also add "group=foo"
# to the end of this line if you want to use a group other
# than the default "root" (but this may have side effect of
# denying "root" user, unless she's a member of "foo" or explicitly
# permitted earlier by e.g. "sufficient pam_rootok.so").
# (Replaces the `SU_WHEEL_ONLY' option from login.defs)
# auth       required   pam_wheel.so
```

So, uncomment this `auth` line, then `su` will be restricted to members of group `root`. Or uncomment and add `group=sulogin`, if you want to restrict to the `sulogin` group.

Comment: This does does not solve my problem. I have updated the question.